# How get field type in field layout

Tags: field, frontend, entry-form

I'am building a website (craftcms 3.4+) where I'll need frontend entry editing. Therefore I'll need the fieldlayout of an entry. This is what I'll have:

```
{% for tab in entry.fieldLayout.tabs %}
        <div class="form__row">
            <h3>{{ tab.name }}</h3>
        </div>
        {% for field in tab.getFields() %}
            <div class="form__row">
                {% if field.type == 'plainText' %}
                    <label for="etg">{{ field.name }}</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fields[{{ field.handle }}]" value="{{ attribute(entry, field.handle)}}">
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem of this is that `field.type` not excist. I'll need that because of the different field types I'm using. How I'll get the th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `instance of` test ([docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tests.html#instance-of))

```
{% if field is instance of ('craft\\fields\\PlainText') %}
```

or use `className` ([docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/functions.html#classname)).

```
{% if field.className == 'craft\\fields\\PlainText' %}
```

In full:

```
{% for tab in entry.fieldLayout.tabs %}
    <div class="form__row">
        <h3>{{ tab.name }}</h3>
    </div>
    {% for field in tab.getFields() %}
        <div class="form__row">
            {% if field is instance of ('craft\\fields\\PlainText') %}
                <label for="etg">{{ field.name }}</label>
                <input type="text" name="fields[{{ field.handle }}]" value="{{ attribute(entry, field.handle)}}">
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can see [all native Craft field types here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/fields.html#field-types).